# Listen to checked input="checkbox" and split equal percent for input="text" Javascript Jquery events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, jquery-events

There is this code that I am trying to figure out, there are four instances:
[image]
When I select the first checkbox, it appears 100% on the box from it's right.
When the second checkbox is selected, it appears 50% on each of the inputs.
When the third checkbox is selected, it splits equally to 33% for each input.
And so it does for all the selected checkboxes, 25% each.

Also, when I deselect one, it comes back. It splits the percentage equally between the number of selected checkboxes.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: And were is the code you have so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/rjq0eb3y/20/

I've used Vue.js to quickly model how this would work, however, the same concepts can be applied without Vue in, essentially the exact same way.

**JavaScript**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    percentage: 0,
    numberOfChecked: 0
  },
  methods: {
    update(event) {
      if (event.target.checked)
        this.numberOfChecked += 1
      else
        this.numberOfChecked -= 1

      if (this.numberOfChecked === 0)
        this.percentage = 0
      else
        this.percentage = 100 / this.numberOfChecked
    }
  }
})
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <template v-for='id in 4'>
    <input type='checkbox' v-bind:id='id' v-on:click='update' />
    <label v-bind:for='id'> {{ percentage === 0 ? '' : percentage + '%' }} </label>
  </template>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
input:not(:checked) + label {
  color: white;
  user-select: none;
}
```